# Почему не обновляются данные при запросах?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Есть такой код

```
import React from 'react';
import AuthService from './AuthService'
import axios from 'axios'; 
const Auth = new AuthService();
const token = Auth.getToken();


  // Contaner Component (Ignore for now)
  class TodoApp extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        // Pass props to parent class
        super(props);
        // Set initial state
        this.state = {
         name:'',
         description:'',
         done:false,
         data:[],
         term:'',
         payloadName:'',
         payloadDescription:'',
         payloadDone:false,
         postData:'',
         deleteData:undefined


        }
        this.proxyUrl  = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/';
        this.apiUrl    = apiUrl;
        this.config  = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             Authorization:'Token '+token
          }
        };
      }
      componentDidMount(){
        axios({
          method:'GET', 
          url:this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl,
          headers:{Authorization:'Token '+token},
          data:null})
          .then((res) => {

           this.setState({data:res.data,
            loading:false
         })
          });

      }
      // componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      //   axios({
      //     method:'GET', 
      //     url:this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl,
      //     headers:{Authorization:'Token '+token},
      //     data:null})
      //     .then((res) => {
      //       this.setState({data:nextProps.res.data})

      //     });

      // }

      getData =()=>{
        axios({
          method:'GET', 
          url:this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl,
          headers:{Authorization:'Token '+token},
          data:null})
          .then((res) => {
           if(res.data !== this.state.data){
            this.setState({data:res.data})
           }

          });
      }
      handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        term:event.target.value });;
      }
      payloadhandleCheck =()=> {
        this.setState({payloadDone:!this.state.payloadDone})
      }
      handleCheck = () => {
        this.setState({done:!this.state.done})
      }
      handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const config = {
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
             Authorization:'Token '+token
          }
        };
        const payload = JSON.stringify({       
          name:this.state.name,
          description:this.state.description,
          done:this.state.done
   });
        axios.post(this.proxyUrl+this.apiUrl,payload,config)
        .then(res=>{
         this.setState({postData:res.data})
        })


        }

        onDeleteClick = (id) => {
          axios.delete(this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl +  id + '/',this.config)
          .then(res=>{
            this.setState({deleteData:res.data})
          })
      }
      onUpdateClick = (id) => {
        const payload =  JSON.stringify({       
          name:this.state.payloadName,
          description:this.state.payloadDescription,
          done:this.state.payloadDone
   });

        axios.put(this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl +  id + '/',payload,this.config)
      }
    handleUpdateContent = () =>{
      this.setState({update:!this.state.update})
    }
    render(){

      return (

        <div>
        <div>
          <h1>Add you task </h1>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} className="todoform">
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="name" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Desciption:
            <input type="text" name="description" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <label className="label--checkbox">
            Done:
            <input type="checkbox" name="done" checked={this.state.done} onChange={this.handleCheck} className="checkbox"/>
          </label>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
        </div>
          {
            this.state.data.map(datas =>{
              return (
                <div className="cart" key={datas.id}>
                <h1>{datas.name} </h1>
                <h2>{datas.description} </h2>
                <h3>{String(datas.done)} </h3>
                <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.onDeleteClick(datas.id)}>Delete task </button>

                <a onClick={this.handleUpdateContent}> Update task </a>
                {this.state.update?
                  <div>

          <h1>Add you update </h1>
        <form className="updateForm">
          <label>
            Name:
            <input type="text" name="payloadName" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <label>
            Desciption:
            <input type="text" name="payloadDescription" onChange={this.handleChange} />
          </label>
          <label className="label--checkbox">
            Done:
            <input type="checkbox" className="checkbox" name="payloadDone" checked={this.state.payloadDone} onChange={this.payloadhandleCheck} />
          </label>
          <a onClick={()=>this.onUpdateClick(datas.id)}>Update </a>
        </form>

        </div>

                 : null}

                </div>
              )
            })
          }
        </div>

      );
    }
  }
  export default TodoApp;
```

Но почему при запросах на сервер на добавление, изменение и удаление item-ов, данные не обновляются, а когда я перезагружаю страницу то всё окей - данные есть.Как это можно исправить?Буду благодарен за ответы

Comment: на каких обработчиках у вас отправляются данные на сервер?
`onUpdateClick `, `onUpdateClick `, `onDeleteClick `? Если на этих, предположу что вам после этих обработчиков нужно вызвать `getData` и обновить state. Тогда должно все обновиться.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру на мой комментарий `put` запрос, для остальных запросов идентично:

```
onUpdateClick = (id) => {
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    name: this.state.payloadName,
    description: this.state.payloadDescription,
    done: this.state.payloadDone
  });

  axios.put(this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl + id + '/', payload, this.config)
    .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          if (data.status == 200) {
            axios({
                method: 'GET',
                url: this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl,
                headers: {
                  Authorization: 'Token ' + token
                },
                data: null
              })
              .then((res) => {
                if (res.data !== this.state.data) {
                  this.setState({
                    data: res.data
                  })
                }
              });
          })
      }
    }

}
```

или проще, у вас можно вызвать `this.getData()`:

```
onUpdateClick = (id) => {
  const payload = JSON.stringify({
    name: this.state.payloadName,
    description: this.state.payloadDescription,
    done: this.state.payloadDone
  });

  axios.put(this.proxyUrl + this.apiUrl + id + '/', payload, this.config)
    .then((data) => {
        if (data) {
          if (data.status == 200) {
            this.getData();
          })
      }
    }

}
```